# Download a file using python from a webpage without opening the webpage

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web

I was looking for a way to write a script that will download a file from a specific website but without opening the website itself. I want everything to happen in the background.

The website is morningstar and a specific link for the example is this one:
https://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=MSFT
in this page, there is a "Button" (it is not really declared as a button but as a Hyperlink, the `<a>` tag in HTML)

I added a photo in the bottom so you can see for yourself exactly the way they wrote the code.

Anyway, I saw that when I clicked the button the href attribute actually calls a javascript function which then creates the links from which the file will be downloaded.

I am looking for a way that I can write a script and give it the link I want, for example, the link above, and the script will download this specific CSV file from that page into a folder of my choice.

I was looking at some selenium tutorials but I couldn't find much help for my specific problem.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "without opening the webpage"? Why is this important?

Comment: Hi perhaps PhantomJS might work in this case? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26440563/11746212

Comment: If you know the url of the download you can use [requests](https://likegeeks.com/downloading-files-using-python/)

Comment: @K753 only if the site is static, but I'm reasonably certain morningstar uses dynamic scripting

Comment: have you tried their API? not sure if its free but here is a link. https://developer.morningstar.com/apis/investment-screener-api-us?regions=350#GettingStarted

Comment: @Chris 
Well, that is not the most important thing but I would like for the code to work cleaner and let's say I would like to download 20 different files on the same run of the program. that will open a 20 different browser's tabs, wouldn't it? just seems not so clean...

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I use:

```
import requests

url = 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x150'

dashboardFile = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)

open('d:/dev/projects/new-wave/dashboard.pdf', 'wb').write(dashboardFile .content)
```

Oh, and depending on the size of the file you would want to download in chunks. A quick search of: "python download large file in chunks" will help.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I would search a little bit about requests in python. I just uploaded the photo I forgot to post. So I don't know if that would work what you suggested but I would look into it.
Thank you again.

Comment: You are welcome. Here's a link on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16696317/4208845